# Como detectar quando o usuário digita algo invalido ou queira encerrar o programa antes?

Tags: c++, variáveis, conversão-de-tipo

Estava fazendo um exercício em C++ que pega o menor e o maior numero digitado pelo usuário, tentei deixar algo mais automático, onde ele vai digitando ate não querer mais. Então estou tentando definir que se o usuário digitar 'k' por exemplo, o código para e as verificações é feita só com os números que foram digitados antes. e caso ele informe outra letra sem ser o 'k' que é para a saída, o programa informa dizendo que n é um valor valido.

Consegui fazer o código, e ele ate que esta funcionando, mas não consegui passar dessa etapa de reconhecer o 'k' ou outra letra, já que a array que recebem os valores do usuário é int/float. e o caractere 'k' é do tipo char, ai acaba dando erro na comparação.

Tem um jeito de fazer comparações  entre tipos de variáveis diferente? ou converter, alguma coisa? Ainda sou iniciante no C++

```
float valor[20];
 float menor;
 float maior{ 0.0 };

 std::cout << "Informe os valores para vermos qual é o menor e maior numero!\n(Maximo permitido são 20 valores)(pressione K para encerrar)\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        std::cin >> valor[i];
        menor = valor[0];
            if (valor[i] == 'k') {
                i = 20;
            }
        menor = valor[i]<=menor?valor[i]:menor;
        maior = valor[i]>maior?valor[i]:maior;
        system("cls || clean");
    }
std::cout << "\nO menor numero digitado foi: " << menor;
std::cout << "\nO maior numero digitado foi: \n" << maior;
```

Comment: Favor adicionar o código que você produziu para que alguém possa compreender melhor o contexto e te ajudar.

Comment: adicionei o código

Comment: Você pode fazer a leitura da linha com `getline` e verificar seu conteúdo como caractere e, se for o caso, converter a string lida para um float utilizando a função `stof`. Para não restringir os valores passíveis de serem informados também utilize o valor inicial de maior como sendo o primeiro número lido.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez o que voce precisa seja algo do tipo:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int menor;
    int maior;

    std::cin >> menor;
    maior = menor;

    for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
    {
        int atual; std::cin >> atual;
        if(!std::cin) // verifica se a entrada é válida
        {
            break;
        }

        menor = std::min(atual, menor);
        maior = std::max(atual, maior);
    }
    std::cout << "Maior: " << maior << '\n';
    std::cout << "Menor: " << menor << '\n';
}
```

Repara que o primeiro valor é lido antes do laço. Repara também que, o laço quebra se *qualquer* valor inválido for inserido.

Embora seja uma operação trivial é preferivel usar as funções std::min e std::max ao invés de fazer tudo "manualmente" para que o código fique mais legível.

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Experimente a abordagem a seguir.

**Considerações:**

Se você for permitir numero "0" então terá que verificar de uma forma um pouco diferente o valor digitado e a comparação.

Outra coisa, parti do principio de que o menor numero é um número elevado, mas, você pode melhorar isso, colocando o menor numero igual ao valordigitado quando o menor estiver com "0" por exemplo.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    float valordigitado;
    float valor[20];
    float menor=100000000;
    float maior{ 0.0 };

    std::cout << "Informe os valores para vermos qual é o menor e maior numero!\n(Maximo permitido são 20 valores)(pressione K para encerrar)\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        std::cin >> valordigitado;
        if ( valordigitado == 'k' ) {
           i = 20;
        }
        else if ( valordigitado > 0 ) {
           valor[i]=valordigitado;           
           menor = valor[i]<menor?valor[i]:menor;
           maior = valor[i]>maior?valor[i]:maior;

        }
    }

    //system("clear");
    std::cout << "\nO menor numero digitado foi: " << menor;
    std::cout << "\nO maior numero digitado foi: " << maior;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```